# Why is a $\pi$ phase added on reflection and why do things change with absorption?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, reflection

1. Mathematically, how does a $\pi$ phase shift appear upon reflection of light off a optically denser medium?
2. Why is it always $\pi$?
3. If the medium is absorptive it is no longer $\pi$?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32122/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I've attempted an intuitive explanation as an answer to the original question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32122/phase-shift-of-180-degrees-on-reflection-from-optically-denser-medium. How intuitive this is you'll have to judge for yourself!