# Path difference in newton's ring experiment

Tags: optics, waves, interference

I do understand the derivation of Newton's rings. But I couldn't realise the meaning to add $\lambda/2$ in the expression :**path difference($x$)$=2tn\cos r$** i.e **$x=2tn\cos r+\lambda/2$** for obtaining the optical path difference.
Where,n=ref. index
 I am pretty sure $\lambda/2$ is taken for the phase change of light by $\pi=180^\circ$ {phase diff$=kx=(2\pi/\lambda)x$}. But, why is $\lambda/2$ directly added on the expression as $x=2tn\cos r$ already considers optical path for the calculation of path difference.
I wish someone could help me to construct the physical picture of the situation. Just I need is why $\lambda/2$ is added in the above equation, I presume I could do rest of the thing myself. 
THANK YOU!

Comment: @belarus: That's an answer. The full answer in fact. Please don't use comments to give full answers.

Comment: @ ACuriousMind; I don't think you received my question well.

Answer (score 1):

When light reflects from material with refractive index bigger than the medium it is coming from it obtains phase difference $\pi$

Analytical aspect of this phenomena is well explained in first answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150661/does-light-change-phase-on-refraction) question. If don't want to go into E&M details just check the picture in third answer to the [same](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150661/does-light-change-phase-on-refraction) question.