# Evolution of the operators in Mach-Zehnder interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, interference, quantum-optics, interferometry

I have trouble understanding how the operators that change the initial state, change when adding extra splitters. As an example, I will use an idealized Mach-Zehnder interferometer where the splitters have no thickness.

[image: Image from this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207810/mach-zehnder-interferometer-two-output-interference-pattern-question]

I am using the picture from [Mach-Zehnder Interferometer: two output interference pattern question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207810/mach-zehnder-interferometer-two-output-interference-pattern-question)

I will use the labeling of the modes as follows:

- purple = $a$
- red between splitter 1 and splitter 2 = $b$
- green between splitter 1 and splitter 2 = $c$
- between splitter 2 and screen 1 = $d$
- between splitter 2 and screen 2 = $e$

Now, I know that the creation operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ creates the photon at the very beginning of the diagram.

Then, it changes with splitter 1 as follows

$$\hat{a}^\dagger \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger) \hat{a}^\dagger$$

since now apply the $\hat{a}^\dagger$ operator first, and then the operator that 'creates' the other two paths after the first splitter (including the phase $i$).

Now, my problem is how do I take this and add a second splitter since I have two different paths ($b$ and $c$)?

Comment: The identity you've used, $\hat{a}^\dagger \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger) \hat{a}^\dagger$, is incorrect - it should read $\hat{a}^\dagger \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger)$. Where did you see that version?

Comment: I thought it was that way because we first act on the state $| 0 \rangle$ with the $a$ operator to get $|1\rangle_a$ and then with the splitter 1 operator to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle_b |0\rangle_c + i |0 \rangle_b |1 \rangle_c)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity you've used, 
$$\hat{a}^\dagger \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger) \hat{a}^\dagger
\qquad \text{(wrong!)}
$$
is incorrect. Instead, what you need to do is this:
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger) 
$$
That is, the operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ is exactly equal to the linear combination   of operators $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{b}^\dagger + i \hat{c}^\dagger)$, or in other words the operation of creating a photon on channel $a$ is exactly identical to the superposition of creating photons on the $b$ and $c$ channels.

If you want to keep going and add the second beam splitter, you do the same but with the relevant combination of modes:
$$
\hat{b}^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{d}^\dagger + i \hat{e}^\dagger).
$$
Similarly, you should have a relationship between $\hat{c}^\dagger$, $\hat{d}^\dagger$ and $\hat{e}^\dagger$, where you should ensure that [the matrix that connects the two sets is unitary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185155/phase-added-on-reflection-at-a-beam-splitter/448873#448873).

More importantly, you need a *second* such relationship coming from the beam splitter, which relates the $\hat{b}^\dagger$ and $\hat{c}^\dagger$ operators with the *empty* port of the first beam splitter:

> [image]

The first time you see this, it feels extremely weird that this empty port is so important, but it is a crucial ingredient. In short, the port looks empty to you, but it still contains vacuum fluctuations, and those vacuum fluctuations can have a strong effect on the experiments downstream from the beamsplitter.

Once you put all of this together, you will be able to construct explicit relationships between the input modes ($\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{f}^\dagger$) and the output modes ($\hat{d}^\dagger$ and $\hat{e}^\dagger$) of the interferometer, so you can

- change input states like $\hat{a}^\dagger|0\rangle$ into output states, by simply substituting $\hat{a}^\dagger$ for the relevant combination of $\hat{d}^\dagger$ and $\hat{e}^\dagger$, or
- Express your observable (which is likely to be some combination of the number operators $\hat{d}^\dagger\hat{d}$ and $\hat{e}^\dagger\hat{e}$, since you're detecting intensity at the screens) in terms of your input operators $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{f}^\dagger$, which can then be used to take expectation values for different input states, and so on.

Hopefully that clarifies how the formalism is meant to be used.