# Standing Waves in a String of two Linear Densities

Tags: waves, reflection, boundary-conditions, density, string

Given a string with sections of two linear densities like this:
[image]

Does the point where the two linear densities meet have to be a node if a standing wave is produced? Are there alternatives? Could I perhaps produce a standing wave where the meeting point is an anti-node?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32122/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219825/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: Well, draw yourself some pictures.  What happens if the interface is neither a node nor an anti-node?  How do the waves reflected at the interface interfere with the waves reflected at the end of the string?  I suspect that looking at a couple cases will lead you to the answer.