# Standing waves on compound string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, oscillators, continuum-mechanics, string

Please help with this question - No data is given as such. The 2 strings have different thickness. Initially, minimum frequency of the thick string is 120 Hz. Then if we push the cart such that only the thick string lies in the horizontal plane, then what will be its minimum frequency?
My basic question is, in a compound string, can the junction be an antinode? And can it be a random point anywhere between node and antinode? 
[image]

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/compound-wire-standing-wave.666433/

Comment: Possible duplicates :  Standing waves on a compound string, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138960, Standing Waves in a String of two Linear Densities, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243343

Comment: I saw those but still had a doubt so posted this question. Please excuse me for that.