# How to calculate phase shift upon total internal reflection?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, dielectric

I learned that there is usually a phase shift upon total internal reflection. How to calculate it depending on the refractive index of the dielectrics and angle of incidence? Does the phase shift occur for polarized light?

Comment: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node53.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wave reflection, boundary conditions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219825)

Comment: I have a trouble reading through the equations in the link you posted. Would you care to explain what the symbols employed represent?

Comment: The formulae are more easily seen at the start of this article : https://scholarworks.uno.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1073&context=ee_facpubs

Comment: I do this calculation in my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89986/26076) about the Goos-Hänchen effect; the last equation in the answer should help you, and you can read through the derivation to see exactly how it is applied.

Answer (score 1):

This question is now fully answered in the *Wikipedia* article on [Total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection), which I have recently rewritten.