# Why a wave, travelling in a lighter medium, inverts upon reflection from an interface of a denser medium?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, reflection

As exactly the title says:

- Why a wave, traveling in a lighter medium, inverts upon reflection from an interface of a denser medium ?
- What are the things that go on at the interface ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32122/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Nice animations and non mathematical descriptions here http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/reflect.html. It is a combination of "density" and "stiffness" which determines what happens at a boundary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Phase shift of 180 degrees on reflection from optically denser medium](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32122/)

Comment: you need to take a look at the boundary conditions at the interface while applying the wave equation...