# Phase shift during wave reflection

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, boundary-conditions

I know that Electromagnetic waves undergoes a phase shift when reflected from a denser optical medium. Does this conclusion also hold for other mechanical waves like sound wave reflecting from water surface?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32122/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a wave  travelling from rarer medium is incident on an interface seperating it from a denser medium and undergoes reflection it gets a phase change of π  .This is valid for both light and sound .  Wikipedia link for further reading and diagrams  :- httpss://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_phase_change